# weird php .so error

Tags: linux, php, centos, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

Do I need to recompile or rebuild or something? I never had this issue before.

```
/usr/bin/php: /opt/xml2/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/php)
/usr/bin/php: /opt/xml2/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /opt/xslt/lib/libexslt.so.0)
/usr/bin/php: /opt/xml2/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /opt/xslt/lib/libxslt.so.1)
```

Comment: Are you running a cpanel server with apache on this machine ? If not, then can you provide few details about what you are running and what versions.

Comment: yea, it is cpanel

Answer (score 2):

As I have seen this issue with the cpanel server only, so I am assuming that you are using the same.

For the fix, this is what you need to do:

# mv /opt/xml2 /opt/xml2.bak

Then re execute EasyApache from WHM > EasyApache (Apache Update) or via shell using the command /scripts/easyapache –force

This should fix the problem.

This [blog](https://myeasylinux.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/no-version-information-available-required-by-php/) explains the same.

Comment: Yea that sounds about right. Any idea what causes it?

Comment: Not really .. never digged further when I faced the issue

Comment: Also, would be great if you can accept it as the answer ... will help other people who are looking for the solution for same problem.